# Trigger on Opportunity Page

Tags: trigger, opportunity

I have created the following trigger:

```
trigger UpdateOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {    
    Map<Id, Opportunity> recordTypeMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT RecordType.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE ID IN :Trigger.new]);  

    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate && recordTypeMap.get(opp.Id).RecordType.Name == 'SGI Opportunity' && opp.StageName != 'Lead 0%') {
            if(opp.Win_Reason__c == 'No Competition/Sole Source') {
                opp.Competitor_s__c = 'No Competitor/Sole Source';
            }

            if(opp.Unsolicited_Bid__c == 'Yes') {
                opp.Competitor_s__c = 'No Competitor/Sole Source';
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

It's a simple trigger that will set a Multi-Select Picklist value equal to 'No Competitor/Sole Source' if 2 conditions are true. However, I'd like to change the requirement just a little bit. I do want opp.Competitor_s__c to default to 'No Competitor/Sole Source' BUT I want the user to be able to change the value, if they deem it necessary. Is this possible?

As always, thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: No exactly sure what you mean. You have a trigger to set it but you do not want the trigger to set it (You state you want user to set it)?? If so, disable the trigger and the user can select it instead.

Comment: Yeah man, that's what I'm thinking.. Ok, so the question is now, is there any way to set a multi select picklist to a default value and then the user can change it?

Comment: I do not believe so (based on criteria) only the trigger could do that. BUT if you see the answer posted by @guy it would potentially meet your needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it matches the requirement 100% but a simple solution would be to check if the field is filled before updating it. That way in any case that the field is filled (either automatically or manually) it will not be changed.

This is the updated code:

```
    if(opp.Win_Reason__c == 'No Competition/Sole Source' && opp.Competitor_s__c == null){
        opp.Competitor_s__c = 'No Competitor/Sole Source'; 
    }

    if(opp.Unsolicited_Bid__c == 'Yes' && opp.Competitor_s__c == null){
          opp.Competitor_s__c = 'No Competitor/Sole Source';
    }
```

This is what will happen:

1. user enters an opportunity without a Competitor__c (but matching the other requirements)
2. trigger code will update the Competitor__c, since Competitor__c == null

or:

1. user enters an opportunity with a Competitor__c (and matching the other requirements)
2. trigger code will not update the Competitor__c, since Competitor__c != null

Note that any future updates to the Opportunity will not trigger the Competitor__c update, since it is not null anymore. Only if someone empties the Competitor__c field, the code will trigger again and refill it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would there be any way the user would be able to select a value that's not 'No Competitor/Sole Source',  if the condition is true?

Comment: The trigger code you posted is not related to whatever is visible or selectable by the user on the GUI. Only after the user has submitted the page (e.g. by clicking 'save') will the trigger code be run.

Comment: Right, once the page is saved and the user selected Yes for Unsolicited bid, I want the multi-select picklist to default to 'No Competitor/Sole Source', and then the user can still pick a Competitor from the list if there is an actual competitor. 99% of the time it's going to be 'No Competitor/Sole Source', so that's why we want it to default to that value, but every so often there could be a competitor.

Comment: So my solution should work then, as long as you keep the field editable on the page layout.

Comment: Thank you so much. I believe your solution will work.. Can you explain how it works, because I don't really understand why it works. I'm fairly new at coding, and the explanation would help tremendously. Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: Because guy's code sets opp.Competitor_s__c to 'No Competitor/Sole Source' if  the there was no value selected by users in the front end. That was your objective anyway, right?

Comment: Indeed. I added a small explanation to the answer as well.